# AppScript running twice when closing page immediately

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m creating a custom form and linking it with Google Spreadsheet. After the data from the form is updated into the spreadsheet, then it will run/update the google Calendar, another spreadsheet and finally send email to the form submitter. Now if the submitter submits the form and closes the page while the code is still running, it seems like my code runs twice and causes the data to be duplicated in the spreadsheets too.

My Javascript code :

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
     document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",runProgram);
   },false);
 
function runProgram() {
  //Check Data validation
   updateForm();
}

function updateForm(){
    google.script.run.executeProgram(dataArray);
}
```

Here is GAS Code :

```
function executeProgram(dataArray){
    //get Data array and set value in Spreadsheet App
    newSubmission();
}
```

newSubmission function is to  run EmailApp, update other sheets and update calendar.

If I remove newSubmission function from executeProgram, the function will only run once, but if I put it back, the function runs twice like the picture below. I’m suspecting my current duration was too long resulting in double execution for the GAS code.

[Here is the execution page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPDyZ.png)

And here is the running time:

With newSubmission function, the execution time to complete is 23 sec.
Without newSubmission function, the execution time to complete is 3sec.

Anyone know why it runs twice and how to solve it?

Comment: We like the [mcve] to be small but it also has to be able to reproduce the error.  I'd say that you missed the mark on that.

Comment: @Cooper I have edited my question above, let me know if you still need the code.

Comment: I will be busy for most of today and may not be able to come back to this for a while.

Comment: @Cooper Sure, do come back when you are free because I really need help on this

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue and nobody know why that happen. But how about you prevent users from changing/closing the page while the script still running on the back by using window alert box.

```
function updateForm(){
    google.script.run.executeProgram(dataArray);
    window.onclick = function(){
       alert("please do not close the page");
    }
}
```

With this whenever user click the windows, the alert box will kinda prevent it from happen.